# how to share files using xmpp library

Tags: ios, xcode, xmpp

In my application I am using xmpp library for chatting. In this case we are passing text to xmpp library to send the text to other user.

Now I want to send files like image or video using xmpp library to other user.
Is there any possibility of doing so?

Comment: If you library supports XMPP file transfers then there is the possibility in doing so.

Comment: As you didn't say what library you use, I can only tell you to look through its docs for mention of support for "Jingle File Transfer" or "SI File Transfer". These are the new and old methods for FT in the XMPP world.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can perform file sharing using XEP-0065 or IBB using SIFileTransfer. 
Checkout this link.

https://github.com/faizanrefai/FileTransfer-2